# Очерёдность доступа к мьютексу в C++

Tags: c++, многопоточность, синхронизация

Есть 2 потока (`a`, `b`) и 1 мьютекс. Мьютексом уже владеет какой то другой поток (не `a` и не `b`). Потоки `a` и `b` выполняют `lock()` и становятся в ожидание мьютекса.

В какой очерёдности потоки `a` и `b` получат доступ к мьютексу, когда тот освободится? Например, если первым встал на блокировку(выполнил `lock()`) поток `a`, а потом `b`, должен ли первым войти поток `a`, а после него `b` или не обязательно?

Comment: Не обязательно. Случайным образом если приоритет одинаковый. Если приоритет разный - предпочтение будет у того, у которого приоритет выше (но не обязательно получит первым высший, приоритет определяет долю вероятности).

Comment: Нет не должен. Никакой очередности нет. Более того, если вашему коду такая очередность важна - значит вы что-то делаете неправильно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не обязательно. Случайным образом если приоритет одинаковый.

ОС работает по принципу, что есть "массив" или очередь ожидающих выполнения потоков. В простейших ОС случайным или последовательным образом выбиралось кто сейчас будет работать. В современных ОС ведётся статистика использованого времени потоками, и предпочтение отдаётся самому обделённому временем потоку с учётом приоритета, для того что бы время было примерно равномерно распределено между потоками в рамках одного приоритета.

При одинаковом приоритете вероятность 50%, но приоритет будет отдан "бездельнику", поэтому если первый поток давно не работает, а второй уже набрал статистику времени и остановлен совсем недавно - то управление вполне с большей вероятностью может получить именно первый поток.

Если приоритет разный то могут быть особенности, но как правило предпочтение отдаётся потоку с более высоким приоритетом, но не всегда.

Comment: Рекомендовал бы Столлигнса, "Операционные системы", раздел 5.4. Говорить о конкретном методе, распространенном даже не в одной версии ОС, как о всех ("в современных ОС"). Общим (и то в такой неопределенно-пожелательной форме) названо стремление избегать голодания. Но как именно - с очередью ли, с учетом приоритетов или как еще - в общем случае не определено. Так что так вполне может быть, но это отнюдь не является обязательным. Кстати, теоретически даже привязка `mutex` к примитивам ОС не обязательна :)

Answer (score 6):

В общем случае порядок не определен. На стандарт ссылку привести не могу, но в книге Джосаттиса "[Стандартная библиотека С++](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1837-6.html)" в разделе 18.5.1 говорится о том, что порядок блокировок не определен.

P.S. Что, как я понимаю,  не мешает каким-нибудь стремящимся гарантированно избежать голодания компиляторам + операционным системам применять свои стратегии для того или иного упорядочения вызовов блокировок...

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*